# Two "For event in pygame.event.get()"

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, event-handling, pygame

I have done `def` for to make two functions. I do not want to join these because I want to be able to make something where I can do one without doing the other. The problem is I have two `for event in pygame.event.get()`s and whenever I try to use one after the other as the first pygame.event.get() **gets rid of all events after it is called**, so I can't use other events in the second function. For example, in

```
def Func1():
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      #Do something

def Func2():
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      #Do something
```

If I do any of these, the second wont work:

- do Func1, and the next line do Func2 (Func2 won't work)
- do Func2, and the next line do Func1 (Func1 won't work)
- do Func1 alone (Will work)
- do Func2 alone (Will work)

I did some experimenting to find out that the `for event in pygame.event.get():` gets rid of all avents after it is called, which is why I am having a problem. Anyone have any ideas how to bypass this? Thanks and tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to do the above (if possible depending on what you need doing) would be like this. You have one event loop that will call different functions based on what key has been pressed.

```
def Func1():
    print('key pressed')

def Func2():
    print('mouse pressed')

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        Func1()
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        Func2()
```

If you absolutely must have one event loop per function, define the event list at the start of the frame and pass it to the functions.

```
def Func1(events):
  for event in events:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      #Do something

def Func2(events):
  for event in events:
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      #Do something

pygame_events = pygame.event.get()
Func1(pygame_events)
Func2(pygame_events)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encounter this issue recently.
I might don't know which way is the best way to resolve this issue with refactoring the code, but there is a simple way to get the same effect by using pygame.key.get_pressed() to handler the keyboard event while a key is pressed. So that you don't worry about calling the event.get() twice in one loop.

```
def function():
     for event in pygame.event.get():
                
         if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
             #do something

run = True
while run:
    key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    if key_pressed[K_ESCAPE]:
        run=False
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).